# Auto pop up box if string is defined in URL

Tags: javascript, php, html

sorry if my explanation is not clear. Been searching on Google for almost an hour and failed to find anything that I could understand/get working.

I have this code:

```
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Editing</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<form action="report.php" method="POST" id="reppur" name="reppur1">

<input name="id" type="text" id="id" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="status" type="text" id="status" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="amountOwed" type="text" id="amountOwed" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="hoursComplete" type="text" id="hoursComplete" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="hoursAuthorized" type="text" id="hoursAuthorized" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="nextPayment" type="text" id="nextPayment" class="form-control" required><br>       
</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I was trying to make it so when the URL was like "http://example.com/index.php?active=YES" then the popup box would automatic popup on page load, else if there is nothing defined it will act as normal.
Please be very clear in your helpful answers as I am still new to html. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before the `</html>` part of your page (at the bottom), check if the `$_GET['active']`-variable exists in the QueryString and if it equals to YES. If it does, show the popup.

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['active']) && $_GET['active'] == "YES"): ?>
    <script>
        alert('It exists');
        // Or what ever javascript-code you want to run...
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

All parameters in the QueryString (?key=value) ends up in the `$_GET`-superglobal-array. `isset()` checks if the array key exists and if it does it checks if the value matches "YES". Important note: The check is case sensitive so `?active=YES` will match while `?active=yes` won't.

The reason we put this in the bottom of the page is simply so the body (with your HTML-code) already is loaded when your javascript is triggered.

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Okay but how would I make it make the auto popup work? Using my code above that is not java.

Comment: It's javascript, not java ;-) Are you asking us to code a modal-popup for you? There are hundreds (if not thousands) of scripts and tutorials for that.

Comment: If the `modal-content`-element has `display: none` in the css.. then you can do: `<div class="modal-content" style="<?php echo isset($_GET['active']) && $_GET['active'] == "YES")? 'display: block;': '' ?>">` on the element to make it visible if the GET-variable matches.

Comment: As you can see. My modal code is in my question. I want it to be displayed .

Comment: Except from your CSS..  if there are no CSS on your page... it should always be visible as it is...

Comment: You have posted your HTML-markup. The HTML-markup should show when you enter your website. If the above HTML isn't shown, then you probably have some CSS (styling) like a `<link rel="stylesheet"...` in the top of your page that hides it. If that is the case... I have no idea what it does and how to show it if I'm not allowed to see it. Where did you get the "modal"-markup?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: Then I suggest you read bootstraps documentation on how to show modals... Then you can still use the above example on how to trigger the modal on page load.... and add "bootstrap" as tag to your question.